# $ ( \forall \epsilon > 0, \mathcal{B}_{\epsilon}(x) \cap F \neq \emptyset \Rightarrow x \in F ) \Rightarrow F $ is closed

Tags: real-analysis

So I was thinking, I know how to prove it from right to left, but this way I just cannot figure out.

I was thinking about using contraposition, so assuming F is not closed. But I get stuck at knowing $\mathcal{B}_{\epsilon}(x) \cap F \neq \emptyset$.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a matter of understanding the logical assumption you're given. Let's make it clear:

Let $x \in \overline{F}$, we will show $x \in F$:

By assumption it suffices to show $\forall \epsilon > 0$,  $B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap F \neq \emptyset$ (for then $x \in F$!)

So, let $\epsilon$, since $x \in \overline{F}$ it is guaranteed that $B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap F \neq \emptyset$, and we're done.

Hope this clarifies..

Answer (score 0):

Your hypothsis means that every $x$ which belongs to $\overline F$ actually belongs to $F$. In other words, $\overline F\subset F$. But you always have $\overline F\supset F$ and therefore you are assuming that $\overline F=F$. And this is equivalent to the assertion that $F$ is closed.